# How can i specify a hasOne relationship while there are many record in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

there are two tables,Task and Report

```
Task(id,name,latest_report_id);
Report(id,content,feedback,task_id);
```

`one task` has `many report` but it only has one latest report.I wanna how can I get this hasOne relationship in Phalcon 4.0
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but according to the documentation, you can use conditional relationships.  When you set up your relationships in Task:

```php
$this->hasMany("report_id", Report::class, "id");// This is the standard one-to-many
$this->hasMany(
    "report_id", 
    Report::class, 
    "id", 
    "params" => [
        "order"=>"date_entered DESC",
        "limit"=>1
    ],
    "alias" => "LatestReport"
);
```

This assumes `date_entered` is the field in the `report` table you can use to determine which report is the "latest".

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models-relationships#conditionals

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention the database engine but in case its mysql, you might in the future set up the relations before making the models and use the Phalcon's cli tool [(Devtools)](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/devtools) and will setup the relationship in the models for you

to get the latest report from the `Task` model add this relation in `Task` model file

```php
$this->belongsTo('latest_report_id', 'Report', 'id', ['alias' => 'latestReport']);
```

this would lookup `Report` table using `findFirst` with `id = latest_report_id` condition

if this is not the case please update the question with more details